# listado muy grande de puntos

Tags: base-de-datos

En primer lugar, agradecer vuestra ayuda.
Estoy iniciando un proyecto y me surge la primera gran duda antes incluso de haber programado algo y quisiera saber más sobre si será posible o es inviable. De ahí que recurra a ustedes.
Dispongo de un listado de puntos, con coordenadas (UTM o Geográficas), muy grande. Son, aproximadamente, 170000 puntos.
Quisiera tenerlos integrados en una aplicación para, al insertar las coordenadas de otro punto, que me diga cual es el que está más cercano (o sea, tendría que calcular la distancia del punto insertado a cada uno de los puntos de la lista y ver cuál es la distancia menor).
Es posible crear una lista con tal magnitud de puntos en phyton?
Reitero. Muchas gracias.
Saludos.

Comment: Cuál es la estructura de la tabla? Qué DBMS estás usando? No sería mas eficiente hacer una consulta que te devuelva la info buscada que traerte esa cantidad de info y hacer el proceso en Python o el lenguaje que sea?

Comment: Hola. Por ahora, el listado de puntos lo tengo en excel. Entiendo y creo que no es la mejor opción, por lo que voy a investigar cual sería la mejor opción para crear la base de datos sobre la que se haría la consulta desde python, que es lo que propones, y me parece muy acertado. Muchas gracias.